# Weird shadow behind popover view in iOS 13.1 and 13.2 only

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Even though pop over background colour is clear there is a weird shadow  behind the popover view this issue is happening only in 13.1 and 13.2 and it is working fine in 13 and below

I can see in view hierarchy that UIWindow/UITransitionView/_UICutoutShadowView has image view with shadow image which is only in 13.1 but image view has empty image in 13

```
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
controller.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
controller.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = controller
controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
controller.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = FilterBackgroundView.self
present(controller, animated: false)
```

[image: strange shadow image]

Comment: Any way to remove this background color Priyanka M V ?

Answer (score 4):

On UI inspect there is a UIImageView of type _UICutoutShadowView which is causing it. So I managed to fix this by creating a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView and hiding this ghost view.

```
override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        // iOS 13 (or newer)
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let transitionViews = window.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITransitionView" }
            for transitionView in transitionViews {
                let shadowView = transitionView.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UICutoutShadowView" }.first
                shadowView?.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, can be used till new solution is available.

Comment: would you tell us where to apple the UIImageView under UIContextMenu ?